# How to change the background color of the active nav-item

Tags: html, css

I am using bootstrap navigation tabs in my page, I want to change the background color and text color of the active tab.Following is the HTML code for the tabs

```
<div class="tab-content">
            <div class="os-tabs-controls">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills text-upper pl-2 pr-2">
                    <li class="nav-item tabs p-2">
                        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#leavelist" aria-expanded="true">
                            LeaveList
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item tabs p-2">
                        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#procurementlist" aria-expanded="false">
                            Procurement List
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

My CSS is as follows

```
<Style>
.nav-item a:active{
        color: white;
        background-color: red;
    }
</Style>
```

The above code is working fine when i clicks on tab but immediately it changes back to the default color styling.
Kindly anybody look into the issue and help me to get it working.

Comment: give your full code which you trying.

Comment: I think the page is reloading whenever you click on the navbar link, but considering you added ids to your href, i assume they link to a div so this should not happen

Comment: no the page is not loading when i am clicking on navbar link

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with jQuery:

```
$('.nav-item a').click(function(e) {
    $('.nav-item a').removeClass('current_page_item');
    $(this).addClass('current_page_item');
});
```

CSS:

```
.current_page_item {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

JSFiddle here: [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/6w0sy8gp/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Its working now, actually i overwrite the default styling with my custom styling
by adding following css

```
<style>
.nav-pills .nav-link.active, .nav-pills .show > .nav-link {
        color: #F0F8FF;
        background-color: #CD0B0B;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, add class at the referring link on the page

```css
.active{
        color: white;
        background-color: red;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous"><script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="tab-content">
            <div class="os-tabs-controls">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills text-upper pl-2 pr-2">
                    <li class="nav-item tabs p-2">
                        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#leavelist" aria-expanded="true">
                            LeaveList
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item tabs p-2">
                        <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#procurementlist" aria-expanded="false">
                            Procurement List
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

If you want same effect on hover you can simple add it on nav-link class.

---

For one page website:

```js
$('body').scrollspy({
  target: '#myNavbar',
  offset: 50
});
```

```css
.navbar-nav li>a:hover,.navbar-nav li>a:focus,.navbar-nav li.active {
        color: white;
        background-color: red;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous"><script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="tab-content">
            <div class="os-tabs-controls">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills text-upper pl-2 pr-2">
                    <li class="nav-item tabs p-2">
                        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#leavelist" aria-expanded="true">
                            LeaveList
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item tabs p-2">
                        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#procurementlist" aria-expanded="false">
                            Procurement List
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        
<div id="leavelist">Section One</div>
 <div id="procurementlist">Section Two</div>
```

Comment: actually with my original code it works for a moment but goes back to the default color stying

Comment: @MAK it's normal, because work only when is active. my code it's simple change color base to the page.

Comment: @MAK i see now is one page website i add second snippet.

Comment: @MAK have you see my answer and test it again?